# How to get input from user using JAVASCRIPT and compare it with array if that value is present in array show present if not show not present.

Tags: javascript

I have been trying this and i have no idea what i am doing , i think it will use for loop but i dont know how to use it

```
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript">
    function check(a)
    {
        if(a===list[a])
    {
    document.write("Number is Present");

    }else{
    document.write("Number is not Present");
    }
    }
    </script>
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript">
    var list=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
    var n = prompt("Enter any Number");
    check(n);
    console.log(list);
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you think `list[a]` means? You should learn the basics of Javascript and arrays.  Look at the `includes()` method, but beware of the difference between numbers and strings.

Comment: `list.indexOf(a) > -1  ? 'Present' : 'Not present'`

Comment: Re the dupetarget: Although it's asking about an "object," really it's just asking about a value (an object *reference*) in an array. Your numbers are also just values in an array, so the answers there answer this question, too. (SO's definition of a "duplicate.") See those answers for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have. You should learn some javacript. [Code.org](http://code.org) is a fun place to start

```js
// Define your list before the function
var list=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
function check(a) {
  a = parseInt(a); // Convert your user input string to integer
  if(list.indexOf(a)>-1) { // Check if value exists in list
    document.write("Number is Present");
  }else{
    document.write("Number is not Present");
  }
}
// Prompt user for data
var n = prompt("Enter any Number");
check(n);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your reply.   if(list.indexOf(a)>0)  change it to  if(list.indexOf(a)>-1) then it works properly.

Comment: You are right! I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function check(a) {
  if (list.indexOf(a) > -1) {
    document.write("Number is Present");
  } else {
    document.write("Number is not Present");
  }
}

var list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
var n = prompt("Enter any Number");
check(n);
console.log(list);
```

The problem with your code is that the parameter 'a' that you are sending to the check function, is the value you entered. But when you check

```
if(a===list[a])
```

the list[a] is the number with the index 'a'.

For example, if i pressed 3, then list[3] would mean 40. (since arrays start from 0)

Comment: That doesn't work... the number gets passed as a `String`

Answer (score 0):

Try `indexOf`

```
function check(a)
{
    if(list.indexOf(a) > -1)
    {
        document.write("Number is Present");  
    }
    else{
        document.write("Number is not Present");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is just comparing `a` with the array value present at that index in the array. For example if user types `a= 10` then `a==list[a]` means check if `list[10]` equals to `10` that means if value in list array at index `10` is equal to the typed value. And of course you'll get undefined many times if user typed a big number.

What you are looking for is `.indexOf`. This will return you the `index`if element is in the array or `-1` otherwise.

```js
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14]
var n = prompt("type a number");

console.log(typeof n);

n = parseInt(n);

list.indexOf(n) > -1 ? console.log('In there') : console.log('Not there');
```

Moreover, you've array of integers and anything you type in prompt will be converted to string. Check `console.log(typeof n);`. So you'll have to parse it into `int` to check for your array elements.